# "Anther link is `to` quora", is this expression grammatical and idiomatic?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, expressions

this question comes from this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/419529/247356), where I asked

> I googled "uniform prior" and got a link to Prior probability, which
>   uses the term without an explanation or a definition.
>
> Anther link is `to` quora, which does not give an concrete example.

I am concerned about whether `Anther link is to quora` is grammatical and idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

**Quora** is a name and should be used with a capital letter. "Another" (which you have spelled incorrectly) in this case means additional, "link" is a noun and "Quora" is a name